# File types used for MISB KLV Encoding

Tags: embedded-resource

I'm curious as to what file types are used for Motion Industry Standards Board KLV (Key Length Value). I've read the documentation at the MISB site, which is quite huge. It indicates, to my understanding, that MPEG-2, is usually used so I tried to get an idea as to what to look for in file extensions to recognise files that have the capability for embeding KLV metadata.

My question is: If a file has an extension like these - *.TS  *.mpg, does that indicate potential KLV embedding? Are there any more types ? Can an active video stream from a camera contain KLV?

Any resonse or elaboration is appreciated. Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 1):

As MISB docs state, only MPEG video streams for full motion video and NITF images for high resolution wide area coverage.

Mostly MPEG-TS streams, AFAIK.

You can scan your files for strings like "KLVA" or some of the keys defined in the standard to quickly detect such files with high confidence.

Answer (score 1):

By scanning the titles of documents on the MISB site, one can glean that KLV can be encoded in `AES3 Serial Digital Audio Streams`, `SMPTE 291 Ancillary Data Packets`, and `SDP (Session Description Protocol)` [streams]. Reading a quick bit of the guidance .pdf also reveals that:

> ...MPEG-2 Transport Streams are a common multiplexing device for multiple data streams...

...but this does not limit KLV to only the MPEG-2 TS.

As a direct answer to your question: if the KLV stream is contained within an MPEG-2 Transport Stream, then yes - either `*.ts` or `*.mpg` files would qualify. (As would any other file capable of storing/containing an MPEG-2 Transport Stream.)

If you have further questions, reach out to me.